# How to calculate two values and display the difference in a textbox

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am new in creating applications using Visual Studio 2010. I am creating an application where it calculates the difference of a two values. I have two textboxes where the user will input 2 numbers. What I want is that it will calculate the difference of two values then display the difference in another textbox. Is this even possible? If yes, how can I do this? Please help.

Comment: Looking at your profile and it seems you are "New" for quite sometime and it will be better if you start learning the basics.. may be a book? c# calculator :  http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+calculator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: Have you done same with VS 2008? it shouldn't be much different.

Comment: Winforms or ASP.NET, what have you tried? This question sounds as simple as `Txt3.Text=(int.Parse(Txt2.Text)-int.Parse(Txt1.Text)).ToString();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get two values from their textboxes and convert them into numbers.

```
int val1 = Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
int val2 = Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text);
```

Calculate the result

```
int result = val1 - val2;
```

Store it in the 3rd textbox.

```
TextBox3.Text = result.ToString();
```

You should use `Exceptions` to catch situation when someone has entered an incorrect value in one of the textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should just assign result variable to the textbox:

```
textbox3.Text= (Convert.ToInt(textbox1.Text) - Convert.ToInt(textbox2.Text)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to sample as below. Hope this what you want.

```
int number1, number2;
// Checks text box value can change to int or not.
if (int.TryParse(txtbox1.Text.Trim, out number1) 
    && int.TryParse(txtbox2.Text.Trim, out number2))
    txtbox3.Text = (number1 - number2);
```